# Can I find frequently occuring phrases in an array of strings where the phrase only forms part of each string?

Tags: ruby, arrays, pattern-matching

This has been asked before but wasn't ever answered.

I want to search through an array of strings and find the most frequent phrases (2 or more words) that occur within those strings, so given:

```
["hello, my name is Emily, I'm from London", 
"this chocolate from London is  really good", 
"my name is James, what did you say yours was", 
"is he from London?"]
```

I would want to get back something along the lines of:

```
{"from London" => 3, "my name is" => 2 }
```

I don't really know how to approach this. Any suggestions would be awesome, even if it was just a strategy that I could test out.

Comment: what's the definition of a phrase here?  anything more than 1 word?

Comment: And what's your try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
x = ["hello, my name is Emily, I'm from London", 
"this chocolate from London is really good", 
"my name is James, what did you say yours was", 
"is he from London?"]

words = x.map { |phrase| phrase.split(/[^\w\'']+/)}.flatten
word_pairs_array = words.each_cons(2)
word_pairs = word_pairs_array.map {|pair| pair.join(' ')}
counts = Hash.new 0
word_pairs.each {|pair| counts[pair] += 1}
pairs_occuring_twice_or_more = counts.select {|pair, count| count > 1}
```

Comment: sorry, that's only for 2 word phrases but you should be able to adapt it by adding a loop for the word_pairs_array generation to include the longer phrases

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a one stage process, but it is possible. Ruby knows what a character is, what a digit is, what a string is, etc. but it doesn't know what a phrase is.

You'd need to:

1. Begin with either building a list of phrases, or finding a list online. This would then form the basis of the matching process.
2. Iterate through the list of phrases for each string, to see whether an instance of any of the phrases from the list occurs within that string.
3. Record a count of each instance of a phrase within a string.

Although it might not seen it, this is quite a high level question, so try to break down the task into smaller tasks.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I might be misunderstanding, but I can't really build a list of phrases because the whole point of the exercise is I'd have no idea what the common phrases were in advance. The only thing I can think to do is to look for common words (in the above example lets say 'from') and then look for what the word that comes after that match is ('London'), and then see if next time we see the word 'from' it is also followed by 'London', but I don't know how to do that to cover phrases of all lengths - could tree recursion help? Or am I barking up the wrong tree altogether?

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that might get you started. This is brute forcing and will be very very slow for large data sets.

```
x = ["hello, my name is Emily, I'm from London", 
"this chocolate from London is really good", 
"my name is James, what did you say yours was", 
"is he from London?"]

word_maps = x.flat_map do |line|
  line = line.downcase.scan(/\w+/)
  (2..line.size).flat_map{|ix|line.each_cons(ix).map{|p|p.join(' ')}}
end

word_maps_hash = Hash[word_maps.group_by{|x|x}.reject{|x,y|y.size==1}.map{|x,y|[x,y.size]}]

original_hash_keys = word_maps_hash.keys
word_maps_hash.delete_if{|key, val| original_hash_keys.any?{|ohk| ohk[key] && ohk!=key}}

p word_maps_hash #=> {"from london"=>3, "my name is"=>2}
```